# Problem with detecting badge with PN532 and Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, nfc, pn532

I have been trying to detect an tag using the PN532 module that I bought from amazon here:

https://www.amazon.ca/ASHATA-Controller-Raspberry-Interface-Switching/dp/B07XFNDHNS

I followed the tutorial here:

http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=PN532_NFC_Module_for_Raspberry_Pi

I tried using both I2C or SPI, but both results just give me the following when I run nfc-poll:

```
nfc-poll uses libnfc 1.7.1
NFC reader: pn532_spi:/dev/spidev0.0 opened
NFC device will poll during 30000 ms (20 pollings of 300 ms for 5 modulations)
nfc_initiator_poll_target: Success
```

It seems like the PN532 is connected to the Pi properly, but the tag is not being detected or printing any info. I am beginning to wonder if the problem is with the PN352 device itself. Maybe I got a faulty one?

Thanks

Comment: Your nfc-poll results looks OK, implying that the PN532 module should be working properly. I have followed your tutorial and installed libnfc 1.7.1 smoothly, EXCEPT I could not find and config file and needed to write the config file myself. My reader can detect a tag OK. Please read my answer for more details. Please feel free to ask me to do other tests for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Answer***

*Update 2020mar29hkt2040*

*Part 1 - libnfc v1.17 I2C config tested OK*

The OP has no luck in testing libnfc I2C mode and SPI mode.  I tried I2C mode and found everything OK. I guess the OP has not set the config file, or has not set "auto scan = true". See my example libnfc171 config file in Appendix A. PS - (1) My NFC reader can detect a tag without any problem.  (2) I am using Rpi4B buster 2020mar13.

---

*Part 2 - Now testing SPI mode 2020mar29hkt2044*

Sunfounder config instructions recommends lowering SPI speed 50kHz.  So I have changed the /bbo/config.txt file as shown in Appendix F.

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***References***

(1) [The OP's NFC RFID Controller Module](https://www.amazon.ca/ASHATA-Controller-Raspberry-Interface-Switching/dp/B07XFNDHNS)

(2) [SunFounder Rpi PN532 NFC Module Tutorial](http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=PN532_NFC_Module_for_Raspberry_Pi)

(3) [Libnfc NFC Library](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php/Libnfc)

(4) [Libnfc Configuration Manual](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php/Libnfc:configuration)

(5) [Libnfc Main Page](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php/Main_Page)

(6) [Libnfc: configuration](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php/Libnfc:configuration)

(7) [Libnfc: nfc-list](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php/Libnfc:nfc-list)

(8) [MIFARE Card](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php/MIFARE)

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - Installing libnfc 1.7.1*

[image: nfc config]

---

*Appendix B - Reading a tag*

[image: reading a tag]

---

*Appendix C - NFC Reader Tested*

[image: NFC]

---

*Appendix D - My NFC readers and tags*

[image: nfc readers and tags]

---

*Appendix E - PN532 NFC reader V3 Wiring*

[image: pn532 v3]

---

*Appendix F - SPI configuration for testing PN532 using libnfc 1.1.7*

[image: spi config]

---

Comment: Goddammit. `allow_autoscan=true` fixed this. Was wondering if there was something wrong with my PN532. Thank you.

Comment: Gald that you solved the problem.  Cheers.